# How to count number of occurrences of a consecutive string of the same number in R

Tags: r

I have a string of 0's and 1's like this in R:

```
x<-c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1)
```

I would like to count how many strings of 1's there are (i.e., with no 0's in between).  For my example here, I'd like to get the output 4, since there are 4 strings of 1's that are consecutive.

Let me know if I should clarify what I mean.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: show us what you've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try `rle`

```
sum(with(rle(x), lengths[!!values])>1)
$[1] 4
```

Or

```
sum(with(rle(x!=0), lengths*values)>1)
```

---

Or with `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
sum(table(rleid(x)[x!=0])>1)
#[1] 4
```

Comment: Or `with(rle(x), sum(lengths > 1 & values == 1))`, haha

Comment: Thank you!  What if there is an NA in between any of these numbers?  Would these work as well?

Comment: @Ig929 Perhaps `sum(with(rle(x1!=0), lengths*values)>1, na.rm=TRUE)` should work

Comment: Sorry - will do in the future